# How intelligent are the Weeping Angels?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

In Dr. Who, we see the Weeping Angels as nothing more than predators (albeit interesting and sometimes terrifying ones), but just how smart are they?  Do they communicate among themselves?  Do they do anything more than hunt for food, or are they the equivalent of a scary, space-time goldfish?

Answer (score 8):

They Weeping Angels appear to be quite intelligent. They use a soldier named Cleric Bob in "The Time of Angels" to communicate with the Doctor and River Song and indicate that the Angels were causing Amy Pond to count down because it pleased them to terrify her. Evidently they enjoy playing with their food. You can add cruelty to their list of attributes.

While they don't seem to communicate in most circumstances, they appeared to want to talk to the Doctor during "The Time of Angels" episode because they wanted information from him. This need for information regarding the "temporal rupture" means they are smarter than your average "scary space-time goldfish."

> The Angels could take the consciousness of someone who had died and speak through it to communicate, as they used the Cleric Bob, whom they killed, to talk with the Eleventh Doctor. (TV: The Time of Angels/Flesh and Stone) They also possessed the ability to communicate with each other over long distances, even when frozen; they perhaps have some telepathic abilites to help coordinate their teamwork. (TV: The Angels Take Manhattan) **[Tardis Data Core > Weeping Angels](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel)**

Comment: Good point.  I have forgotten most of "Time of the Angels"

Comment: I don't blame you.